# Is it possible to assign a String but also add to an Integer from a returned tuple in one line?

Tags: python, function, return, tuples

For example, suppose I have some strings which never leave a loop, but a number counter that I need globally. Instead of...

```
outside_int = 0

def string_Grabber(stuff):

    my_string = ''
    my_number = 0

    for i in range(who_cares):
        #stuff that concatenates my_string
        if this_happens():
            my_number += 1

    return my_string, my_number

for things in another_loop:

    loop_string = string_Grabber(things)[0]
    outside_int += string_Grabber(things)[1]
```

...is there a way to do it in one line, so that I don't have to call the (potentially expensive) function twice? Like:

```
loop_string, outside_int = stringGrabber(things)(0, += 1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do it in one line.
You can do it inside function:

```
def string_Grabber(stuff):

    my_string = ''
    my_number = 0

    for i in range(who_cares):
        #stuff that concatenates my_string
        if this_happens():
            my_number += 1

    return my_string, my_number + outside_int
```

Comment: That's true. I'll just add extra arguments to the function, but thank you for entertaining my curiosity.

Comment: Adding "outside_int" as argument in function will make it local for function only. Global variable "outside_int" will not change. Do not add it as argument in function.

Answer (score 1):

I have one quick solution, you can add a temporary variable to catch the integer and then add it to the global value as shown below.

```
outside_int = 0

def string_Grabber(stuff):

   return 'string',1

for things in range(2):
  strring, tmp = string_Grabber('sample')
  outside_int +=tmp
  print(outside_int)
```

returns output

```
1
2
```